# Почему светодиод подключается к GND?

Tags: stm32

Всем привет! Не могу понять, почему анод от светодиода идёт к GND (катод - PC13, анод - GND). Это минус? Что значит GND? При подключении остальных модулей - так же вести всё к GND как минус? Ничего не могу найти по этому поводу.
STM32F103C8xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnd - граунд, земля, он же минус в цепях с постоянным током.

Comment: Спасибо! Оказалось всё просто и логично)